# Chamberlain’s random effect probit model

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, probit

Why is Chamberlain’s random effect probit model referred to as a random effect model, even though the idea behind such a model is to introduce a correlation between the unobserved heterogeneity term, say $v_i$, and the regressors $x_i$?

Answer (score 0):

One typically estimates Chamberlain’s Correlated Random Effects probit model by adding means of the $x_{it}$ variables, $\bar x_i$s, as additional controls and then estimating the standard RE panel probit.

See p. 515-616 in [Adult Wooldridge](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/econometric-analysis-cross-section-and-panel-data-second-edition) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I may ask for some advice. I have performed the Hausman test on the full dataset which indicated that I should use a fixed-effect model. Now, I want to account for the sample selection in the dataset, thus I need to estimate the probit model. Would it be feasible to proceed with Chamberlain’s Correlated Random Effects probit model in my case? (even though, as I mentioned, fixed effects are preferred but the fixed effect does not exist in probit set-up)

Comment: The details depend on how the sample selection operates, but the CCREP allows for the correlation you are concerned about. That is precisely the point of adding the means.